# Python aws cli from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-interface, boto3

```
import subprocess
import datetime

StartTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
EndTime=datetime.datetime.utcnow()

instances = ['i-xxx1', 'i-xxx2']

list_files = subprocess.run(["aws", "cloudwatch", "get-metric-statistics", "--metric-name", "CPUUtilization", "--start-time", StartTime, "--end-time", EndTime, "--period", "300", "--namespace", "AWS/EC2", "--statistics", "Maximum", "--dimensions", "Name=InstanceId,#call the instances#"])
print("The exit code was: %d" % list_files.returncode)
```

Quick and dirty code. How do I loop from subprocess.run from instances list and print the results also in loop? Having issue also in calling the datetime from StartTime and Endtime format.

Thank you

Comment: Why can you not use the `boto3` library (i.e. Python AWS SDK) instead calling the aws cli through subprocess?

Comment: Hi @AliSamji i was looking for a quicker way to execute this now since i already have the aws cli commands.

Comment: The `boto3` library is not all that complicated and it is easy-to-use since it returns Python objects that you can use. I will post a sample in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use the `boto3` library to call AWS from python. It is fairly easy to translate cli commands to boto3 commands.

```
list_files = subprocess.run(["aws", "cloudwatch", "get-metric-statistics", "--metric-name", "CPUUtilization", "--start-time", StartTime, "--end-time", EndTime, "--period", "300", "--namespace", "AWS/EC2", "--statistics", "Maximum", "--dimensions", "Name=InstanceId,#call the instances#"])
```

Instead of the above, you can run the following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
list_files = client.get_metric_statistics(
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    StartTime=StartTime,  # These should be datetime objects
    EndTime=EndTime,  # These should be datetime objects
    Period=300,
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Statistics=['Maximum'],
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': '#call the instances#'
        }
    ]
```

You can run `help(client.get_metric_statistics)` to get detailed information about the function. The `boto3` library is pretty well-documented. The response structure and syntax is also documented on there.

Comment: how do i loop on the instance part? instances = ['i-xxx1', 'i-xxx2']. i have figured out the  datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(Hours=24), and also having problem with filtering the results it looks like a json?

Comment: You could use a list comprehension. `Dimensions=[{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': iid} for iid in instances]`.

Comment: The results should be a dictionary with nested Python dictionaries, lists, and objects so you should be able to access it like any other dictionary. `list_files['Datapoints'][0]['Timestamp']`

Comment: Thanks, Ali Got the concept.